How can I implement a recursive React context?
Say I want to design a React context that provides a path, and can be nested any number of times. Like this:
<PathProvider path="foo">
  <PathProvider path="bar">
    <PathProvider path="baz">
      <SomeComponent>
    </PathProvider>
  </PathProvider>
</PathProvider>

If I call usePath() (not shown) inside <SomeComponent />, I should get ["foo", "bar", "baz"].
How can I implement this? Here's an attempt:
export interface PathContext {
    path: string
}

export const PathContext = createContext()

export interface PathProviderProps extends React.PropsWithChildren {
    path: string
}

export default function PathProvider({
    path: thisPath,
    children
}: PathProviderProps) {

    const {path: parentPath} = useContext(PathContext) as PathContext<C>

    const fullPath = parentPath ? `${parentPath}.${thisPath}` : thisPath

    return (
        <SettingsContext.Provider
            value={{path: fullPath}}
        >
            {children}
        </SettingsContext.Provider>
    )
}

This works! But, since the topmost provider is still calling useContext, but has no parent context, it throws a console error in the top-most PathProvider:

CreateContext.ts:31 Missing context provider (where is 'path'?)

Is there another way to do this? Can I suppress the error somehow?

Is is a custom error? From where you import createContext and useContext? Is the provided code as with your original version? Ususally React does not complain calling useContext outside of the provider. This is why createContext accepts a parameter, the default value. Try using it like this createContext({path: ''})

@OktayYuzcan despite the fact that the error says CreateContext, I believe it originates from the call to useContext(PathContext) in the topmost PathProvider, which is asking for a parent PathContext that does not exist. The topmost PathProvider by definition will not be able to reach a valid parent context when it calls useContext(PathContext).

useContext does not require having parent provider. I believe there is missing part in the provided code that causes this behaviour.

All you need to do is adjust your types to handle for the condition when useContext returns undefined.

PathContext needs to be typed to indicate that it can be a context with undefined.
While restructuring path from context, you have to provide some default values.
Instead of calling the component recursively. Just create a provider everytime. Althoug SettingsContext is missing from the code you have provided, there is not need to use something like that. Just use PathContext

export interface PathContext {
  path: string;
}

export const PathContext = createContext<PathContext | undefined>(undefined); 

export interface PathProviderProps extends React.PropsWithChildren {
  path: string;
}

function PathProvider({ path: thisPath, children }: PathProviderProps) {
  const { path: parentPath = "" } =
    useContext<PathContext | undefined>(PathContext) || {};

  const fullPath = parentPath ? `${parentPath}.${thisPath}` : thisPath;

  return (
    <PathContext.Provider value={{ path: fullPath }}>
      {children}
    </PathContext.Provider>
  );
}

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const path = useContext(PathContext);
  console.log({ path });
  return <p>{JSON.stringify(path)}</p>;
};

function App() {

  return (
    <PathProvider path="foo">
      <PathProvider path="bar">
        <PathProvider path="baz">
          <SomeComponent />
        </PathProvider>
      </PathProvider>
    </PathProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

Sandbox

I haven't tried this out, but since React is throwing the error, not Typescript, I'm not sure how changing the type could resolve it.

Forgot to mention that I am not calling the component recursively, as there is no need to.
